# php: variable scope within a class

Tags: php, class, scope

I am getting started with classes and have a variable scope question. I am defining a variable $query in one function and need to use it in a second function. However, the second function is not seeing it.

I guess I could pass $query to outside the class and then pass it along ($instance->QueryExecute($query);). But that seems messy, there is no need for $query to exist outside the class.

What is the correct way of solving this?

Thank you,
Louis.

```
<?php
class MyProduct {
    public function QueryBuild() {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM my_product";
    }
    public function QueryExecute() {
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        while ($record = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            foreach ($record AS $key => $value) {
                $this->product[$record["pro_id"]][$key] = $value;
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options to solve your problem and the first is (in my opinion) better than the other:

**Option 1: Return value**

Just tell your build method to return the value and then use it on your other method:

```
<?php
class MyProduct {
    public function QueryBuild() {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM my_product";
        return $query;
    }
    public function QueryExecute() {
        $result = mysql_query($this->QueryBuild());
        while ($record = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            foreach ($record AS $key => $value) {
                $this->product[$record["pro_id"]][$key] = $value;
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

**Option 2: Object field**

You define a field in your class that holds the query. This, however, means that the method `QueryBuild()` always has to be called before you can call `QueryExecute()`, which is not particularly reasonable.

```
<?php
class MyProduct {
    private $query;
    public function QueryBuild() {
        $this->query = "SELECT * FROM my_product";
    }
    public function QueryExecute() {
        $result = mysql_query($this->query);
        while ($record = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            foreach ($record AS $key => $value) {
                $this->product[$record["pro_id"]][$key] = $value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Some things to note:**

- Don't use `mysql_*` functions. They are deprecated and have been replaced with MySQLi and PDO.
- Take a look at coding conventions. Method names should start with a small letter, which makes the code easier to read for everybody used to these standards.

Comment: Option 1 is the wonderful solution I was looking for. It allows me to code in a more clean manner by limiting the use of "$this->". Thank you. Yes, I will stop using mysql_* ...... later.

Answer (score 0):

You define a property in the class, that said I would like to add that `mysql_*` functions are deprecated.

```
<?php
class MyProduct {
    private $query;
    public function QueryBuild() {
        $this->query= "SELECT * FROM my_product";
    }
    public function QueryExecute() {
        $result = mysql_query($this->query);
        while ($record = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            foreach ($record AS $key => $value) {
                $this->product[$record["pro_id"]][$key] = $value;
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```